# Get SIM Number programmatically in flex

Tags: android, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4.5, air-android

i want to get the SIM number programmatically.Is it possible in flex?In android developer guide i saw telephony manager class,likewise do we have anything in flex??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is a SIM Number?  You mean a unique identifier for a cell phone's SIM card?  Or something different?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com +1.  If this IS a mobile question, then we need to take the flex4 tag off as well.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com Yes the unique number.is it possible???

Comment: Who is extra intelligent person who down voted? The question is valid as next version of flex is coming with mobile framework.

Comment: Flex 4.5 focuses on android and major phones

Comment: @Akash Kava.Hey thanks for replying,so is it possible to obtain the SIM number in the current version.Im using flex 4.5.0.

Comment: @naveen I don't know of a way; but am not intimately familiar w/ all of the mobile APIs.  Is this value exposed via Android APIs?  If not; then Flex won't be able to expose it either.  I'm going to retag this as AIR for Android; as that is what would give you the API.  @Akash Kava I perceive that accessing this value could be considered a major privacy/security violation; and I suspect that is why it was downvoted.  Flex 4.5/Flash Builder 4.5 is out today, BTW

Comment: @www.Flextras.com yes the android APIs allows that.there is a class called telephony manager,through that it can be accessed..

Comment: @Naveen I'm guessing it is not possible.  I looked at the SystemCapabilities class docs and it was not exposed there.  I'm not sure where else it would be exposed.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com ya even i dint find any solutions.Thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out... a hack for sure, but a way for you to call into the Java APIs (Android) from Flex Mobile:

http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/